# inf% produced when calculating percentage c++

Tags: c++

So a weird issue occurred when I was testing a roulette bot simulator.
The program is very simple and uses chances from a betting site with a roulette wheel. It has an automated system that can automatically bet for you so to find optimal settings i made this program but encountered a issue id never seen before. When the trial number was lower than about 400, it would give errors when calculating percentage.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "how many trials would you like?" << endl;
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    srand(time(0));
    double yAmount = 0;
    double bAmount = 0;
    double rAmount = 0;
    double gAmount = 0;
    int finaltrial = 0;
    int yellow = 1;
    int blue = yellow + 10;
    int red = blue + 17;
    int grey = red + 26;
    int money = 5000;
    int trialno = 0;
    int trials;
    cin >> trials;
    int result;
    int bet = 10;
    int moneyhigh = 0;
    bool win;
    bool bankrupt = false;
    while (trialno < trials || trials == 0 && bankrupt == true)
    {
        result = rand() % 54 + 1;
        if (result == yellow)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);
            cout << "Yellow";
            yAmount++;
            win = false;
        }
        else if (result <= blue)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
            cout << "Blue";
            win = false;
            bAmount++;
        }
        else if (result <= red)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_RED);
            cout << "Red";
            win = false;
            rAmount++;
        }    
        else if (result <= grey)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_GREEN);
            cout << "Green";
            win = true;
            gAmount++;
        }    
        if (win == true)
        {
            money = money + bet;
            bet = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            money = money - bet;
            bet = bet * 2;
        }
        if (bet > money)
        {
            finaltrial = trialno;
            trialno = trials - 1;
            bankrupt = true;
        }
        if (money > moneyhigh)
        {
            moneyhigh = money;
        }
        cout << endl << " trial: " << trialno << " money: " << money <<              endl;
        trialno++;
    }
    gAmount = gAmount / finaltrial ;
    rAmount = rAmount / finaltrial ;
    bAmount = bAmount / finaltrial ;
    yAmount = yAmount / finaltrial ;
    cout << endl << "Final: " << money << " Peak: " << moneyhigh << endl;
    cout << "Green: " << gAmount << "% " << "Red: " << rAmount << "% " <<     "Blue: " << bAmount << "% " << "Yellow: " << yAmount << "% " << endl;
    cin >> money;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. One that *builds*, and hopefully doesn't do things in the wrong order (like getting input for `money` *after* you use `money` in calculations).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the cin money was temporary just so the program would not close automatically when debugging, ill add the entire program now then.

Comment: Compiler may be  warning you about: `while (trialno < trials || trials == 0 && bankrupt == true)` `||` is lower priority than `&&`

Comment: To keep visual studio from closing on you while debugging, put a breakpoint on the last line.

Comment: Why is `trials == 0 && bankrupt == true` a condition for *continuing* the loop? Are you expecting that to ever become true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop you initialize `finaltrial` with 0. The variable is being edited only in the `if (bet > money)` clause, which means that if the statement is never true, at the end of the loop `finaltrial` will be equal to 0, but you are dividing the results variables with finaltrial, and `gAmount` is defined as double, and `double / 0` returns `inf`

Answer (score 0):

In C or C++, if you divide double datatype by 0, it returns inf. Your variable **finaltrial** gets updated only when **if(bet > money)** return **true.** When this condition fails, **finaltrial** remains 0 and **inf** creates the problem in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to initialize `finaltrial` to 1.

You have initialized it to `0` at the beginning of your program and then you are updating it when a particular condition is met. Regardless of whether tour condition is met or not, you are using `finaltrial` in a division operation. When you do a division operation, you must make sure that you are not dividing by `0` else you will get `inf`. Initializing `finaltrial` to 1 will help you eliminate the issue of getting `inf`( unless you update to value of `finaltrial` elsewhere to `0` )

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the only way of getting an +inf is a floating point division by zero with a positive numerator. Knowing that will help you hunt this problem down like a rabbit. (Note that a negative numerator division by zero gives you -Inf and 0.0 / 0 will evaluate to NaN - not a number.)

Clearly finalTrial is zero which is hardly surprising given that you only change its value on minimal program control paths.